The Android client socket never receives anything from the Windows Java server socket
I've been doing everything by the book so far, and always get this exception, so I really need some advice. I'm trying to implement a client-server pair using my home WiFi.
Is there anything to do with my ISP? The Android Manifest already has INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE (and even MANAGE_EXTERNAL..., though not directly relevant).
Java server:
try {
            FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(file);
            fIS.read(array, 0, array.length);
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            if (!(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().equals("192.168.1.2"))) client.close();
                System.out.println(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " HAS CONNECTED, PORT "
                    + client.getPort());
            if (client.isOutputShutdown()) {
                System.out.println("CLIENT SOCKET HAS BEEN SHUT!!!!!!");
                return;
            }
            OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("SENDING FILE CHUNKS...");
            System.out.println("0000000000000000");
            clientOut.write(array, 0, array.length);
            clientOut.flush();
            System.out.println("111111111111111111");
            client.close();
            System.out.println("333333333333333333");
            System.out.println("FINISHED!");
            }
        catch(SocketException se){
                System.err.println(se.getMessage());
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        catch(IOException ex){
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

Android client:
try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.4",65001,thisLocalAddr,64999);
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(15000);
            array = new byte[13574867];
            InputStream realIS =  clientSocket.getInputStream();
            if (clientSocket.isInputShutdown()) return;
            realIS.read(array,0,array.length);
            fiOS = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    "/Share/file.pdf");
            fiOS.write(array,0, array.length);

            realIS.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            fiOS.close();
        }
        catch (SocketException se) {
              Log.e("MainActivity ", se.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfn) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", nfn.getStackTrace().toString());}
        catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Unknown Host Exception");
            Log.d("FileReceiver: ","dumbo =  " + dumbo.length()) ;
        }

console result:
192.168.1.2 HAS CONNECTED, PORT 64999
SENDING FILE CHUNKS...
0000000000000000
Connection reset by peer
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:54)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.tryWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:410)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:819)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.implWrite(Socket.java:1223)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1210)
    at Main.sendFile(Main.java:53)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)


Please describe the flow of your programs. What should happen and what happens instead? Further you did not tell where you got that exception. On server or client side?

The first client.close(); You should return; there too.

fIS.read(array,.... Check how many bytes are really read as it might be less than wanted. int nread=fIS.read(array,...

realIS.read(array,0,array.length) The same! Check how many bytes are read.

But.... Pretty bad you put the file in an array first. Not needed.

array = new byte[13574867]; Why that 13MB amount? The client does not know the size of the file i would think.

e been doing everything by the book so far, Well you could have done better ;-)

basically that code is not implementing any protocol -- just sending/receiving one chunk of data/packet, but the interfaces/internet are allowed to split the data as needed --usually you must loop until all data is received -- try the (official) tutorial: Lesson: All About Sockets

1.You don't need to test isInputShutdown() when you haven't done anything to cause it. 2. You are testing isOutputShutdown() just after you've closed the socket: it's guaranteed to be true at this point, so the test is pointless. You seem to have a misunderstanding somewhere about these functions. 3. I find it hard to believe 'the Android client never receives anything', Impossible, actually. Surely it receives about 1500 bytes?

Your client reads only 1 block of data and then closes the connection. The next time the server tries to write to the connection, it fails.  The client needs to keep reading until there is nothing more to read.  The best way to handle that is to have the server send the file size before sending the file data, that way the client can know how much data to expect.
For example:
Server:
try {
    File file = new File(path);
    long sizeRemaining = file.length();
    FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(file);
    
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
    if (!client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().equals("192.168.1.2")) {
        client.close();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " HAS CONNECTED, PORT " + client.getPort());

    OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fIS);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(clientOut);

    System.out.println("SENDING FILE CHUNKS...");

    dos.writeLong(sizeRemaining);
    if (sizeRemaining > 0) {
        byte[] array = new byte[1024];
        do {
            int blockSize = (int) Math.min(sizeRemaining,1024);
            dis.readFully(array, 0, blockSize);
            dos.write(array, 0, blockSize);
            dos.flush();
            sizeRemaining -= blockSize;
        }
        while (sizeRemaining > 0);
    }

    client.close();
    System.out.println("FINISHED!");
}
catch(SocketException se){
    System.err.println(se.getMessage());
    se.printStackTrace();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch(IOException ex){
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}

Client:
try {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.4",65001,thisLocalAddr,64999);
    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(15000);
    InputStream realIS = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(realIS);
    
    long sizeRemaining = dis.readLong();
    fiOS = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Share/file.pdf");

    if (sizeRemaining > 0) {
        byte[] array = new byte[1024];
        do {
            int blockSize = (int) Math.min(sizeRemaining,1024);
            dis.readFully(array,0,blockSize);
            fiOS.write(array,0,blockSize);
            sizeRemaining -= blockSize;
        }
        while (sizeRemaining > 0);
    }

    realIS.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    fiOS.close();
}
catch (SocketException se) {
    Log.e("MainActivity ", se.getStackTrace().toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfn) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", nfn.getStackTrace().toString());
}
catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Unknown Host Exception");
    Log.d("FileReceiver: ","dumbo =  " + dumbo.length()) ;
}


Thanks. Replacing the best-effort 3-argument read() with a while loop and 1-argument basic read() solves nearly all of this problem. Concerning the size of the file, I have a way to inform the client side about that, and within this "toy" project, that is evident in the very size of the array byte[13574867] on the client side.

That size is an assumption not a guarantee, and is a waste of memory anyway, especially for a mobile device. Sockets can't send packets nearly that size, so it is not worth it.
